# How to avoid repeating code in a trade strategy that can go long and short

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I have multiple strategies that can make money going long or short. At the moment I have the long side coded separately to the short side but they are a mirror of each other. A basic example might be a close beyond the high/low of the previous candle and to trade in that direction:

```
direction = 'none'
if last_candle['close'] > previous_candle['high']:
  direction = 'long'

if last_candle['close'] < previous_candle['low']:
  direction = 'short'

trade(direction)
```

How could you write that so that you only write the logic once?

Comment: `"this" if True else "that"` See [Conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in the documentation.

Comment: You have three possible results here ('long', 'short', nothing).  You can't really produce one of three results without doing 2 compares.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite make it clear that there is a third option of nothing. I'll update pseudo code. As for not doing 2 compares, of course there needs to be two compares but it's the logic I'm talking about not the end 'direction'. One perhaps crude way of doing it is to negate the values (flip the chart upside down), then flip the direction round.
So it becomes this:
logic = ...
if logic(original_data):
  direction = 'long'
if logic(negated_data):
  direction = 'short'

trade(direction)

This would probably work but I get the feeling there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

there is a bulit-in lib to do it
code:

```
from bisect import bisect
def foo(close):
    previous_candle = {}
    previous_candle['high'] = 100
    previous_candle['low'] = 0 
    choices = ["short","none","long"]
    breakpoints = [previous_candle['low'],previous_candle['high']]
    
    return choices[bisect(breakpoints,close)]
    #return ["short","none","long"][bisect([previous_candle['low'],previous_candle['high']],close)] if you prefer oneliner

print(foo(-50))
print(foo(50))
print(foo(150))
```

result:

```
short
none
long
```